# Total number of points at which a function is necessarily continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose If I'm given a function $f$ with domain $[-1,1]$ such that the coordinates of each point (x,y) of its graph satisfy the $x^2 + y^2 = 1 $. How should I go about finding the total number of points at which the function f is necessarily continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

1. You can modify the traditional nowhere-continuous function which is equal to $1$ on rationals and $-1$ on irrationals to construct a function that is discontinuous in all but a small number of points.
2. You can use the traditional $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity to show that **all** function that satisfy your criterion must be continuous in that small number of points.

---

Alternatively, you can first show that each function that satisfies your conditions must be of the type

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sqrt{1-x^2} & x\in A\\ -\sqrt{1-x^2}& x\notin A\end{cases}$$

for some set $A$. You can use that to show that $f$ is continous at some points, while a proper selection of $A$ shows that $f$ need not be continous anywhere else.

Comment: Does that mean f would be continous for only 2 values of x = 0,1?

Comment: @jimo For only two values, yes. But not $x=0$.

Comment: Only other values that I can see fitting that condition are x=1, -1. 
And why not x=0?

Comment: @jimo If you set $A=\mathbb Q\cap [-1,1]$, then $f$ is not continous at $x=0$. It is only continuous at $x=1$ and $x=-1$.